# Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection parameter name:index

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm trying to add data as one by one row to a datagridview here is my code and it says:

> "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection
>   parameter name:index"

What does this mean? What is the problem in my code?

```
String Sqlstr2 = "select ItemName from Item where ItemID = '" + tbItemID.Text + "'";
db.DataRead(Sqlstr2);
string ItemName = db.dr["ItemName"].ToString(); 

DataGridView dataGridView1 = new DataGridView();

dataGridView1.Columns[0].Name = "ItemID";
dataGridView1.Columns[1].Name = "ItemName";
dataGridView1.Columns[2].Name = "Qty";
dataGridView1.Columns[3].Name = "UnitPrice";
dataGridView1.Columns[4].Name = "Amount";

string firstColum = tbItemID.Text;
string secondColum = ItemName;
string thirdColum = tbQuantity.Text;
string fourthColum = Convert.ToString(UnitPrice);
string fifthColum = Convert.ToString(sum);

string[] row = new string[]{ firstColum, secondColum, thirdColum, fourthColum, fifthColum };
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
```

Comment: Just a simple `dataGridView.Columns.Length` (or something like that) will tell you how many columns it actually has.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You're not adding columns to your `DataGridView`

```
DataGridView dataGridView1 = new DataGridView();//Create new grid

dataGridView1.Columns[0].Name = "ItemID";// refer to column which is not there
```

Is it clear now why you get an exception?

Add this line before you use columns to fix the error

```
dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 5;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer but the data that taken from text boxes and variables still not view in the datagridview when run the program can you help me ?

Comment: Post as new question, You'll get help for sure

Answer (score 50):

The error says "The index is out of range". That means you were trying to index an object with a value that was not valid. If you have two books, and I ask you to give me your third book, you will look at me funny. This is the computer looking at you funny. You said - "create a collection". So it did. But initially the collection is empty: not only is there nothing in it - it has no space to hold anything. "It has no hands".

Then you said "the first element of the collection is now 'ItemID'". And the computer says "I never was asked to create space for a 'first item'."  I have no hands to hold this item you are giving me.

In terms of your code, you created a view, but never specified the size. You need a

```
dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 5;
```

Before trying to access any columns. Modify

```
DataGridView dataGridView1 = new DataGridView();

dataGridView1.Columns[0].Name = "ItemID";
```

to

```
DataGridView dataGridView1 = new DataGridView();
dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 5;
dataGridView1.Columns[0].Name = "ItemID";
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.columncount.aspx

Comment: You're welcome. I feel it's the same answer as the one you accepted, although I came up with it independently (and, I might add, first. :-) )

Comment: Hi Floris. I have got this error "column count property cannot be set on a databound datagridview control c#", at "dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 2;" Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: @Sanjeev4evr - your error message suggests to me that if the property cannot be set, it must have been defined by something else. Perhaps a "databound datagridview" has the column count fixed by the data. Does it work if you leave that line out?

Comment: When I removed that line it thrown the same exception "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index"

Comment: @sanjeev4ever I suggest you post a separate question with more detail about your specific situation, then put a link here.

Comment: Here is the Question.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22904248/column-count-property-cannot-be-set-on-a-databound-datagridview-control-c-sharp.

Comment: @Sanjeev4evr - I see that you found the answer to your other question before I even had a chance to look at it!

Comment: Yes. Thanks for looking back to my question. You can help me some other time.

Comment: Mine was a different case, but this answer gave me the idea that I am trying to add points before adding series to the chart. Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

> what this means ? is there any problem in my code

It means that you are accessing a location or index which is not present in collection.

To find this, Make sure your Gridview has 5 columns as you are using it's 5th column by this line

```
dataGridView1.Columns[4].Name = "Amount";
```

Here is the image which shows the elements of an array. So if your gridview has less column then the `(index + 1)` by which you are accessing it, then this exception arises.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`dataGridView1.Columns` is probably of a length less than 5. Accessing `dataGridView1.Columns[4]` then will be outside the list.

Answer (score 1):

This error is caused when you have enabled paging in Grid view. If you want to delete a record from grid then you have to do something like this.

```
int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
int i = index % 20;
// Here 20 is my GridView's Page Size.
GridViewRow row = gvMainGrid.Rows[i];
int id = Convert.ToInt32(gvMainGrid.DataKeys[i].Value);
new GetData().DeleteRecord(id);
GridView1.DataSource = RefreshGrid();
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Hope this answers the question.