# column count property cannot be set on a databound datagridview control c#

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, datagridview

In My form I have a DataGridView. and controls for input and output data. while displaying data in the gird view. I am calling BindGrid in two occasions. One while formload and other is After adding a new record.

```
 public formAccounts()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindGrid();           
    }

 private void BindGrid()
    {
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source= G:\Sanjeev\TESTDB\DB.mdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=Test123; Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=5";
        conn.Open();
        string constring = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=G:\Sanjeev\TESTDB\DB.mdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=Test123; Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=5";

        using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constring))
        {
            using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM tblAccounts", con))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                using (OleDbDataAdapter sda = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                    using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                    {
                        sda.Fill(dt);
                        //Set AutoGenerateColumns False
                        dtGrdAccounts.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
                        //Set Columns Count
                        ***dtGrdAccounts.ColumnCount = 3;***
                        //Add Columns
                        dtGrdAccounts.Columns[0].Name = "AccountID";
                        dtGrdAccounts.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Id";
                        dtGrdAccounts.Columns[0].DataPropertyName = "AccID";

                        dtGrdAccounts.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Account name";
                        dtGrdAccounts.Columns[1].Name = "Account name";
                        dtGrdAccounts.Columns[1].DataPropertyName = "AccName";

                        dtGrdAccounts.Columns[2].Name = "AccountNumber";
                        dtGrdAccounts.Columns[2].HeaderText = "Account number";
                        dtGrdAccounts.Columns[2].DataPropertyName = "AccNumber";
                        dtGrdAccounts.DataSource = dt;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

If I remove the line `dtGrdAccounts.ColumnCount = 3;` I am getting below error.
    `Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
    Parameter name: index`

After adding the a new record , On button save I am calling BindGrid() method to get the record in the GridiView.

```
string cmdText = "prAddAccounts";
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(cmdText, conn);            
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("AccName", txtAccName.Text.ToString());
 //..... other parameters  to insert record .....
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(cmdText, conn);            
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
BindGrid();
```

Comment: Did you try creating a template cells in datagridview? eg.`dataGridView1.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewColumn(new DataGridViewTextBoxCell()));`

Comment: Or May be adding the columns like this `dataGridView1.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn());`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is when you call the `BindGrid()` again you have to clear it first:

```
string cmdText = "prAddAccounts";
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(cmdText, conn);            
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("AccName", txtAccName.Text.ToString());
 //..... other parameters  to insert record .....

//Clear the binding.
dtGrdAccounts.DataSource = null;
//Bind the new data.
BindGrid();
```

Comment: Got the same error `ColumnCount property cannot be set on a data-bound DataGridView control` when I add a new record and bind the data. But it displayed GridView properly at formload.

Comment: @Sanjeev4evr After another close examination of your code, I think it is fine and should work without my suggestion, except that you probably need to call `dtGrdAccounts.DataBind()` at the end. See my update. The issue is when you call the `BindGrid()` again you have to clear it first.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not getting the DataBind() property. This will be there in Windows forms DataGridView? I am new to windows application. Please never mind if it is silly question.

Comment: @Sanjeev4evr Ah, no, that's for ASP.Net only. Sorry, my bad. Ignore that line.

Comment: What is the similar event of `OnselectedIndexChanged` of Asp GridView to winforms `DataGridView`. When I select a gridView row I need to get the ID of the selected row and based on selected value I'd get the details of the row from the DB.

Comment: @Sanjeev4evr Try `SelectionChanged`.

Answer (score 0):

if you are calling datagridview colum design code more than once then
before setting column property you have to make Gridview data source to null
as shown below

> dataGridView1.DataSource = null;

```
using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                {
                    //add this line of code
                    dtGrdAccounts.DataSource = null;

                    sda.Fill(dt);
                    //Set AutoGenerateColumns False
                    dtGrdAccounts.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
                    //Set Columns Count
                    ***dtGrdAccounts.ColumnCount = 3;***
                    //Add Columns
                    dtGrdAccounts.Columns[0].Name = "AccountID";
                    dtGrdAccounts.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Id";
                    dtGrdAccounts.Columns[0].DataPropertyName = "AccID";

                    dtGrdAccounts.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Account name";
                    dtGrdAccounts.Columns[1].Name = "Account name";
                    dtGrdAccounts.Columns[1].DataPropertyName = "AccName";

                    dtGrdAccounts.Columns[2].Name = "AccountNumber";
                    dtGrdAccounts.Columns[2].HeaderText = "Account number";
                    dtGrdAccounts.Columns[2].DataPropertyName = "AccNumber";
                    dtGrdAccounts.DataSource = dt;
                }
```

Comment: vb.net  Datagridview1.datasource =Nothing