# Cannot open database "name" requested by the login

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database, iis-7, web

I am in process of moving Website and its database on a new server under IIS. I moved and attached the database on the new server. Added web site under the IIS, created App pool and made all the changes to the config file to connect to new data source and updated the root folders path.

The index page loads up fine. When i click on another page link, that communicates with the database and I get an error message that reads "Cannot open database "Cdb_name" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'db_user'.

I have tried several steps but none seems to work. I am not sure if this is a right place to post this question. Any suggestions/help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Can you login to sql server using same user name or password. The problem is most likely:

- User name / password is wrong
- User don't have rights to access to that database

Comment: Yes I can login without any issues. Login works fine.

Answer (score 0):

When you move a login from one SQL Server to a different server, it will not work unless it is a domain account.  Delete the user from the Database; Security section, then add it back via the Security section.  Liek this:

Delete here:

[image]

And add the user and User Mapping to the database here:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However I have tried that as well. I recreated the login, assigned the schema back to the login then I get a different error message. It read "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection"

Comment: This is another matter. Provide more info or close this question and open a new one

Comment: Sounds like you are connecting to th edatabase.  Now it is another issue.  Probably this one:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19162248/index-was-out-of-range-must-be-non-negative-and-less-than-the-size-of-the-colle