# How to make a string as data grid view data source in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, datagridview

I have a string which contains 25 letters and I want to make this string as a data source of a data grid view by converting the string into two dimensional char array of [5,5] elements. The code that I have written is below and error I get on execution is:

> "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection."

```
char[,] keyMatrix = new char[5, 5];
int counter=0;
this.dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 5;
this.dataGridView1.RowCount = 5;
for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    DataGridViewRow row = new DataGridViewRow();
    row.CreateCells(this.dataGridView1);
    for(int j=0;j<5;j++)
    {
       keyMatrix[i, j] = textBox2.Text[counter];
       row.Cells[j].Value = keyMatrix[i, j];
       counter++;
    }
    this.dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

Comment: Which line of code gives the error? You need to have rowcount and columncount  = 5.

Comment: should the dataGridView1 ColumnCount and RowCount be 5?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I thought that it stats from 0 that's why I made it 4 .. thanks now it works :)

Comment: it can be useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19162248/index-was-out-of-range-must-be-non-negative-and-less-than-the-size-of-the-colle

Comment: You should not set the RowCount property of DataGridView. It creates those many rows automatically. And new rows are created by you are added after them. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowcount(v=vs.110).aspx